# adding data to DB and sending email after form submitted

Tags: php, html, email

I don't know why but I don't manage to get any email after html form is submitted.
I can see the data in the DB but I'm not receiving any Emails.
I put some code after the sending that work just fine. Only the mails are not sending.

Please help me.

The PHP file:

```
<?php
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Phone= $_POST['Phone'];
$Email= $_POST['Email'];
$Subject= $_POST['Subject'];
$Message= $_POST['message'];

$conn = mysql_connect("MyServerName", "userName", "password");

mysql_select_db("Mydbname",$conn);


$sql = "INSERT INTO FC(Name, Phone, Email, Subject, Message)
VALUES ('$Name', '$Phone', '$Email', '$Subject', '$Message')";

if (mysql_query($sql, $conn)) {

    $to = "myEmail@test.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = "myEmail@test.com"; // this is the sender's Email address
    $headers = "From: " .  $Email;
    $subject = "Form submission - " . $Subject;
    $message = $Name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $Message . "\n\n" . "His Phone number is: " . $Phone;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);


echo '<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.1;url=http://www.google.com" />
    </head>
    <body>';

echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent! we will contact you shortly.")';
echo '</script>';

echo '</body></html>';

} else {
 echo "something went wrong";
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you get any error? If you don't get error, check if you are getting the mail to your spam.

Comment: Have you checked your php.ini file, if its updated with SMTP server details.

Comment: I cant believe that all my 100000 test mails were sent to my junk email! Thanks a lot and sorry for the stupidity!

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking the return value of mail to see if the message is being accepted by your SMTP server.

Please make sure that mail() is not blocked in your php.ini file.

If your mail function returns FALSE then you would KNOW there's a problem with your mail configuration. If it returns TRUE then there could still be something wrong with your mail configuration. You would need to check the mail log in either case to see if you are getting any errors.

The kicker is that php may be handing off the mail, your server may be sending off the mail, and it may get spam filtered along the way.

You could try explicitly setting the From address using the -f parameter, as explained in example #3 in the php.net manual page for mail:

```
<?php 
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null, 
   '-fwebmaster@example.com'); 
?>
```

So for you, your From address could be invalid based on your hosting specifications but if its not:

```
$from = "-fmyEmail@test.com";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$from);
```